# SMS Lib Call Notification Not working

Tags: java, sms, modem, smslib

I am using SMSLib 3.5.2 library to send/receive sms. I do not receive message when I try to do so by implementing call back methods. Moreover, even the function of incoming call notification is never being called.
Any help would be highly appreciated.....

```
gateway = new SerialModemGateway(MODEM_IDENTIFIER, SERIAL_PORT, BAUD_RATE, MODEM_MANUFACTURER,"");

gateway.setInbound(true);

gateway.setOutbound(true);

ICallNotificationI ic = new ICallNotificationI();
Service.getInstance().setCallNotification(ic);

Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);

Service.getInstance().startService();
```

and the class implementing interface ICallNotification never gets called:

```
public class ICallNotificationI implements ICallNotification {

@Override 
public void process(AGateway gateway, String callerId) {

    System.out.print("Hello Buddy in the call");
    MLog.log(Level.INFO, ".ICallNotification.Process", "We rececived call"
            + " from this number "+callerId);

}
```

Comment: How did you define `Service` ?

Comment: I am not defining Service myself...'The org.smslib.Service is a singleton, so use Service.getInstance() to reference it'
Reference from docs...